# Where are services passed in during HostBuilder ConfigureService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There's some code I'm trying to understand. There's the Program.cs which is:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Aquarius.Management.Services.Worker.Runtime;

await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWorker()
    .Build()
    .RunAsync();
```

The method being called is below:

```
public static IHostBuilder ConfigureWorker(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    return hostBuilder
        .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<WorkerService>();
        });
}

private static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfiguration configuration = context.Configuration;

    /* rest of implementation */
}
```

Where is context and services passed in from? I'm not fully understanding where the parameters for lambda function are being sent here.

Comment: Which one are you confused about? `.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)` or `.ConfigureServices((context, services) => { })`?

Comment: `.ConfigureServices((context, services) => { })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand method chaining

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person WithFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public Person WithLastName(string lastName)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }
}
```

In this example, we have a Person class with two methods: WithFirstName and WithLastName. These methods each take a string parameter and return the current Person instance.

```
var person = new Person()
    .WithFirstName("John")
    .WithLastName("Doe");
```

The person instance would have its FirstName property set to "John" and its LastName property set to "Doe".

Now let's define an extension method for person

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPerson(this IServiceCollection services, Action<Person> configure)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        configure(person);
        services.AddSingleton(person);
        return services;
    }
}
```

This method takes an Action parameter called configure, which is a lambda expression that takes a Person instance.

And now let's use the extension method.

```
services.AddPerson(person =>
{
    person.WithFirstName("John")
          .WithLastName("Doe");
});
```

The configure lambda is applied to a new Person instance, and then that instance is added to the dependency injection container as a singleton service.

Thats how only a person can be used here.

Same goes for your example but with 2 parameters instead of one.

```
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
```

Comment: I see. So essentially because of the nature of extension methods, I shouldn't be concerned about the initialization of the `context` and `services` because in this case it's provided as an abstraction (since I only have access to the interface `IHostBuilder`) ?

Comment: @wya The context and services object are provided by the host builder.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The actual implementation of that is hidden, correct? Since I get the host builder from `CreateDefaultBuilder`?

Comment: The internals of the host builder are hidden, yes.